# Do I need to have AWS CLI to use Boto3?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I have a Django application that needs to use Boto3 to create and manage EC2 instances. When I host the Django application, do I need to install AWS CLI in the server to use Boto3 in the Django application?

Comment: No, you don't need the awscli. Will the Django app itself run in AWS, e.g. on EC2?

Comment: Yes, most likely @jarmod

Comment: OK then it can get the IAM permissions it needs to manage the EC2 instances from an IAM role that you launch the EC2 instance with. Also, be aware of other options to manage EC2 instances such as AWS Systems Manager (here is the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/faq/)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to install the CLI. You just need to use the SDK for Python. With the SDK, you can use IAM Roles. If using EC2, then you would create an Instance Profile, which is nothing but an IAM role where the trusted relationship is EC2, allowing EC2 to act on services on your behalf.

If you are using AWS ECS, then you would create a Task Role or Task Definition Role, which allows ECS to act on services on your behalf. EKS, which works with Worker Nodes, either as a Fargate Profile or Managed Node Group, also uses the same concept of Execution Roles. The bottom line is you can use an IAM role, which will allow you to use Boto3.